# Why are aircraft windshields not unbreakable?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety

> From a materials engineering standpoint, cockpit windshields,
>   typically weighing between 25-40 pounds, depending on the type of
>   windshield build, are typically constructed of several layers:
>
> (1) A glass face-plate, roughly 1/10" thick;
>
> (2) A Polyvinyl Butryal (PVB) layer, about 1/8" thick;
>
> (3) A stretched acrylic layer, approximately 1" thick;
>
> (4) An additional PVB layer, nearly 1/10" thick;
>
> (5) An additional stretched acrylic layer, approximately 1" thick. [Source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140507001219-90103575-cracked-aircraft-windshields-are-not-rare)

But even then, it is not unbreakable. We have had several cases of broken windshields, as mentioned in above source. Also, the co-pilot  in [Varig Flight 254 crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varig_Flight_254) was wounded from a tree, which struck his shoulder after crash landing.

So, why are aircraft windshields not made from unbreakable [Glass Ceramics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass-ceramic) ?

[image]

Comment: Simple: glass ceramics are **not** unbreakable. Furthermore, being a ceramic, it will shatter instead of break the way safety glass does.

Comment: There is no such thing as "unbreakable" so I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: and even if there were the cost and weight penalties would be too high.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Windshields

In the US, aircraft windshields must conform to [14 CFR 25.775 - Windshields and windows](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.775)

> (b) Windshield panes directly in front of the pilots in the normal conduct of their duties, and the supporting structures for these panes, must withstand, without penetration, the impact of a four-pound bird when the velocity of the airplane (relative to the bird along the airplane's flight path) is equal to the value of V C, at sea level, selected under § 25.335(a).

So, windshields are not indestructible partly because they are not required to be.

I guess windshields are not required to be indestructible because bodies like the FAA probably take the view that when an aircraft impacts a massive object at high speed, say a large mountain at 500 MPH, it is of no consequence whether the windshield survives intact at the bottom of a large crater of tiny aircraft fragments. It serves little purpose to make the windshield substantially stronger than the surrounding airframe.

### Glass-Ceramics

Glass Ceramics are not unbreakable. For example a glass-ceramic might have a bending strength of 340 MPa ([Ref p9](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/34/1/Glass-ceramics%20their%20production.pdf))

Comment: Thanks! Just for fun, the only natural choice for windshields would be Aluminium oxynitride (ALON) better known as transparent aluminium from Star Trek IV (aye captain!). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride